# Access JSON via a variable within a gsp

Tags: json, grails, groovy, gsp

There is following JSON structure given:

```
"filter": {
    "1": {
        "value": "swiss"
    },
    "2": {
        "value": "google"
    }
}
```

How to access the variable "value" via an index variable within a gsp template like this?

```
<g:each in="${...}" var="data" status="i">
    ${filter?.i?.value} 
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "key" there is a variable you can use a GString notation like for any other property referenced by variable:

```
${filter?."$i"?.value}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for? It's without index variable.

```
<g:each in="${filter}" var="data" status="i">
    ${data.value.value} 
</g:each>
```

Comment: `data.value.value` (no `?.` needed here, as you iterate over it and it's a map, so data would be an element)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It is also right, but in my case I want to iterate over another structure.